# Remind someone of your favor too much

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there an expression to use when we want to say that someone does you a favor, but they keep talking about it or reminding you of it too much in a way that annoys you?

Comment: People will often use, ‘and he’ll never let you forget it”. As in, “never let Joe do you a favor because he’ll never let you forget it.” or “I did Joe a favor and he’s never let me forget it.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***harp on***, according to the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/harp+on)

> To talk about something to an excessive and tedious degree; dwell on
>   something

In your example:  "I wish X would stop harping on the fact he did me a favor when he drove me to work for a week when my car was in the shop."

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/harp+on) gives the origin of the phrase:

> This expression is a shortening of harp on the same string, meaning
>   "to play the same note over and over." It was first recorded in 1518.

*Harp on* is probably more often associated with complaining incessantly, but it need not mean complaining.

Comment: What does this "twit someone for a favor" thing mean? Does it have anything to do with when people bother you with talking a lot about the favor they've done you?

Comment: @Cheiloproclitic I haven't heard twit used in that way.  twit as a verb means "to tease, taunt, or reproach, often in jest" [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/twit)  I found the reference you found  https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/197199  I doubt a native speaker would use twit in that way.  But "he twitted me for always paying for Joe's coffee when Joe never pays for anybody" would be the way I would use it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with:

He is a favor reminder with so many strings attached to what he has done for you.

Comment: The suggested sentence isn't particularly idiomatic.